# Connectedness of non-zero quaternions

Tags: solution-verification, quaternions

I am trying to prove that set of  non-zero quaternions is path connected. It is $S^3$, but I am not using path connectedness of higher dimensional spheres (except $S^1$ and $S^2$). I am using the book of Artin (Algebra).

For this, given any non-zero quaternion $q$, we can bring it to unit quaternion by map $t\mapsto \frac{q}{\|q\|}t + (1-t)q$ where $t\in [0,1]$.

So from $q$, we can move by a path to unit quternion.

Next, since $q/\|q\|$ is some unit quaternion, it lies on longitude of $S^3$, which is a unit circle passing through $\pm (1,0,0,0)$ where we identify $a+bi+cj+dk$ with $(a,b,c,d)\in\mathbb{R}^4$.

Thus, every non-zero quaternion is path connected to $1$.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: The idea is fine. Some might want to see a description (a parametrization?) of that longitude. Of course, if you have used the concept earlier, then you don't need to. After all, the point of proofs is to communicate the idea. The more common concepts you share with your audience, the more liberties you can take with the details :-)

Comment: I was unable to prove it algebraically or give complete parametric equation of path connecting $q$ to $1$, so came to this short way, in which I have given no parametric equation in later part. However, I don't know whether that argument is (at least topologically/geometrically) correct?

Comment: Mh when working with paths never forget you can compose paths by traveling the first one with twice the Speed then traveling the second one. Here it would suffice to get a path from a point of $S^3$ to $(1,0,0,0)$ so you can concatenate these two paths. Or If that is too tricky take some more stops to make it easier!

Comment: More specifically: Your idea of first having a path from a generic quaternion to a point on $S^3$ is clear. And getting from a point on $S^3$ to $(1,0,0,0)$ is an arc of a unit circle. If you have covered the bit of the set of unit quaternions being a union of various unit circles of various copies of $\Bbb{C}$ inside $\Bbb{H}$, then you are certainly fine. Those unit circles are parametrized by $\cos\alpha(1,0,0,0)+\sin\alpha(0,u_1,u_2,u_3)$, $\alpha\in[0,2\pi]$. Here $(u_1,u_2,u_3)$ can be any unit vector.

Comment: In other words, if your audience is familiar with those unit circles/longitude, you are all set. It clearly does not matter where on the longitude you land - you can continue along it to $(1,0,0,0)$.

Comment: I don't quite understand the question.  Normally one topologizes the quaternions as $\mathbb R^4$, and so the nonzero quaternions are just $\mathbb R^4 - \{ 0 \}$.  Are you really asking about nonzero quaternions and not unit quaternions (the latter is $S^3$)?